# lua timer таймер

Tags: lua, таймер

Здравствуйте. Пишу игру на языке lua на движке corona sdk. Что-то типа РПГ-кликер.
Подскажите, как создать таймер. Чтобы при выборе монстра он запускался и уменьшался

Answer (score 1):

В Corona SDK есть [таймер](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/index.html). Пример использования:

```
local function listener(event)
    print("listener called")
end

-- вызывать "listener" бесконечное число раз, с интервалом в 1 сек. 
timer.performWithDelay(1000, listener, 0)
```

Если функцию нужно вызвать только один раз, то последний параметр в `performWithDelay` можно опустить, или указать явно 1.